# How do I read a loop that has no braces?

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

I'm trying to read the output of this code, but it simply just doesn't make sense to me.

Even after learning that a loop without braces only loops through the first line, the output still makes no sense, at all. Some numbers do, but others just don't.

My code:

```
int n = 8;
int i = 1;
int j = 1;

j = n + 2;

System.out.println (n + " " + i + " " + j );

while (n > 1)
{
    n = n/2;
    for (i = 2; i <= n; i = i+2)
        System.out.println (n + " " + i + " " + j );

    j++;
}
System.out.println (n + " " + i + " " + j );
```

And it outputs:

```
8 1 10
4 2 10
4 4 10
2 2 11
1 2 13
```

I get the 8-1-10
and the   4-2-10

but anything after that, I'm stumped, I don't get how the computer calculates the rest.

Would someone mind going through the rest of the output with me, step by step?

Thank's in advance.

Comment: Execute the code using a debugger, step by step, to understand what the program does.

Comment: May be best thing is add some extra text in each System.out, instead of exact copy/paste. That gives you some clue on which System.out is being excuted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No braces means that the loop affects only the next **statement** that follows the loop.

So

```
for (i = 2; i <= n; i = i+2)
System.out.println (n + " " + i + " " + j );
```

is equivalent to

```
for (i = 2; i <= n; i = i+2)
{
    System.out.println (n + " " + i + " " + j );
}
```

Usually, indentation is used in those cases to make the code more comprehensible, like this:

```
for (i = 2; i <= n; i = i+2)
    System.out.println (n + " " + i + " " + j );
```

**EDIT:** Now, this is the actual answer to the question. It all depends on the different iterations the loop does and how do the variables get incremented.

```
int n = 8;
int i = 1;
int j = 1;

j = n + 2; //This means that j takes the value 10.

System.out.println (n + " " + i + " " + j ); // 8 1 10 So far, so good.
```

Now, on with the iteration:

```
while (n > 1)
{
    n = n/2;
    for (i = 2; i <= n; i = i+2)
        System.out.println (n + " " + i + " " + j );

    j++;
}
```

For the first iteration, we have `n=8 i=1 j=10`, so since `n > 0` is `true` the loop takes place.

```
n = n / 2; //n = 4
```

Then, the `for` (note that it just assigns the value `2` to `i`):

```
for (i = 2; i <= 4; i = i+2) //Since n = 4
```

Since `n = 4`, the only values that `i` can take are `2` and `4`, then the prints are:

```
4 2 10
4 4 10
```

After that, `j` is incremented by one, making it `j = 11`. The condition for the `while` is met again because `n = 4`. `n = n/2` makes `n` take the value `2`, so it enters the `while again`. Let's take a look at the for again:

```
for (i = 2; i <= 2; i = i+2) //Since n = 2
```

This time, the only value that `i` can take is `2` (note that the value of `i` is reset again to `2` while starting the iteration), and that's the print you get.

```
2 2 11
```

Before iterating again, `j++` makes `j` have the value `12`.

On the final iteration, `n = n/2` results in `n = 1` since n is an `int` but this is done inside the while, so it enters again. Now that `n = 1` the loop looks like this:

```
for (i = 2; i <= 1; i = i+2) //Since n = 1
```

`i` is set to `2` and the condition for the for is not met (`2 <= 1` is `false`). Then there is no print this time, yet `j` is incremented to `13` at the end of the while.

In the next iteration you have `n = 1`, that means that the `while`'s condition is not met so the iteration breaks. Finally you have `n = 1`, `i = 2` and `j = 13`. That's the last print you get.

Comment: "The following **statement** of code". You could have many statements in one line.

Comment: Thanks @RobertHarvey for the edit, I was actually adding the same thing.

Comment: The OP stated in the question that they already know this fact. It's likely something else that they're missing.

Comment: Thank you for writing all this out. I completely get it now. 

I'm grateful.

Comment: @user996173 You're welcome pal, I'm glad to be of assistance.

Answer (score 2):

You start the while loop with n = 8, i = 1 and j = 10.

```
start while: (n=8 > 1) is true
n = 4
i = 2 (i <= 4, so do for loop, then change i to i+2=4)
print 4,2,10
i = 4 (i <= 4, so do for loop again, then i = i+2 = 6
print 4,4,10
i = 6 (i <= 4 is false, so exit for)
j++ so j becomes 11

next while:
n = n/2 = 2
i = 2 (i <= 2, so do for loop, then change i to i+2=4)
print 2,2,11
i = 4 (i <= 2 is false, so exit for)
j++ -> j = 12

next while:
n = n/2 = 1
i = 2 (i <= 1 is false, so exit loop)
j++ -> j = 13

exit while.
Final print= n = 1, i = 2 (value assigned in last for loop, loop doesn't get executed so i doesnt get incremented by 2), and j = 13
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hey I just want to thank you so much for writing this out. It helped me understand it clearly. 

You're awesome.